# Disk management drive options

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-management

In disk management when we right click on a drive, doesn't "open" and "explore" perform the same action ? Why have two options for the same action or is there any difference ?[image]

In case of any software/game CD/DVD I remember "Open" runs the installation and explore opens the directory of the disc but whats the difference here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that these are general Windows Explorer actions, and can (or could) be found when right-clicking any folder or drive-letter anywhere. They are **not** specific to the Disk Management app – DiskMgmt just tells Explorer to find the corresponding item and invoke the corresponding action.

Nowadays you only see one "Open" option – starting with Windows Vista, "Explore" was removed because now they do the same thing. But in older Windows versions you used to have both:

[image: (Screenshot of "Explore" context-menu action in Windows 2000)]
[image: (Screenshot of "Explore" context-menu action in Windows 2000)]

<sup>*Fig. 1 – Screenshots of Windows 2000 file manager's right-click menu.*</sup>

**The difference between the two**

Prior to Windows Vista, the file manager (Windows Explorer) did not have the folder-tree sidebar by default. "Explore" would always open a window with the folder-tree visible, while "Open" would open a regular window with your default appearance settings – e.g. [the standard XP sidebar](http://toastytech.com/guis/wxpmycomputer.png) showed file actions, navigation links, as well as selected file details. (Note the "Folders" and "[Search](http://toastytech.com/guis/wxpsearch.png)" buttons at the top.)

In fact the options date to Windows 95, where "Open" and "Explore" would open *entirely different* windows. The file manager in Windows 95 by default used a [spatial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_file_manager) mode, with windows having no sidebar or even button bar at all. Using "Explore" however would activate the 'browser' mode with buttons and a folder sidebar.

[image: (Screenshot of Windows 95 file windows in spatial mode)]
[image: (Screenshot of Windows 95 file windows in explorer mode)]

<sup>*Fig. 2 – Windows 95 screenshots borrowed from the [Toastytech GUI Gallery](http://toastytech.com/guis/win95.html). (You could enable/disable the toolbar in any mode, but you had to use "Explore" to get the folders.)*</sup>

> In case of any software/game CD/DVD I remember "Open" runs the installation and explore opens the directory of the disc but whats the difference here?

Most likely, "Open" just triggers the default double-click action of the drive's folder – therefore, if the CD/DVD has an autorun.inf and double-clicking it in 'Computer' would trigger Autorun, then "Open" will trigger Autorun as well.

"Explore" of course is a separate action that always opens a file browser.

Comment: "In case of any software/game CD/DVD I remember "Open" runs the installation and explore opens the directory of the disc but whats the difference here?" - I know this, I was again referring to the difference in Disk Management.

Comment: Disk Management just calls Explorer and tells it to invoke the same actions. The end result is exactly the same as if you tried to use "Open" or "Explore" on the disk letter item within 'My Computer'.

Comment: And yes I see the difference now...In disk management on opening the left-side side-bar is not expanding to show the sub-folders, but on exploring the left side expand to show the sub-folders as well.

Comment: there is no "Explore" option in "My Computer/This PC" in Windows 10

Comment: There used to be – see updated post. Windows 10 always has the sidebar present, but whoever removed them in Explorer simply forgot to remove them from Disk Manager as well